# change C++ version in visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

How to check the version of C++ in Visual C++ Express Edition 2010 and change it to C++11?
I've tried to use uniform initialization like `std::vector<std::string> v{"Hello" , "World"};`, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot change the C++ language version used by Visual Studio 2010.  It does have partial support for C++11, but since VS 2010 was released before the C++11 standard was finalized, certain features are not exactly in-line with the standard, and furthermore not all features have been implemented.

See [this chart](http://wiki.apache.org/stdcxx/C++0xCompilerSupport) for a list of which C++11 features are supported in various major compilers and the versions at which they became available.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, that is not implemented in the compiler yet, not even in VS 2012.

Comment: However, there is a [preview version](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35515).

Comment: @sftrabbit: But even the preview version won't work with vector. The preview version is a preview of the compiler frontend; C++11 conforming standard library not included.

Comment: @BillyONeal Ah, I didn't realise.

Answer (score 0):

Visual C++ does not support uniform initialization at present time. The [most recent compiler CTP release](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35515) (for Visual Studio 2012, not 2010) has support for it, but that is an alpha-quality product. Moreover, there is no standard library support in there yet, so you still wouldn't be able to use uniform initialization with vector.

(In any case, how would you expect C++**2011** to be supported on MSVC++**2010**?)